# Curl connection options

Tags: c++, curl

I'd like to know how to check out the speed of a file being uploaded in real time using the curl library in C++. This is what I have written:

```
curl_easy_getinfo(curl,CURLINFO_SPEED_UPLOAD,&c);
```

But the manual says that it shows average speed, but even this doesn't seem to work with me, because I can only see a 0.

There is one more thing: How to set an upload limit that works, because if I write this:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAX_SEND_SPEED_LARGE, 100);
```

I get an error 502 message.

Comment: Is the 502 error you mention an HTTP status?

Answer (score 3):

From the [`curl_easy_getinfo`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html) docs:

> CURLINFO_SPEED_UPLOAD
>
> Pass a pointer to a double to receive the average upload speed that curl measured for the ***complete*** [emphasis added] upload. Measured in bytes/second.

`CURLINFO_SPEED_UPLOAD` only works once the updload has completed. Instead, write a progress callback and set [`CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTPROGRESSFUNCTION). Have your progress function calculate the [exponential moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average) for the current speed.

```
progress(curl, fd, len):
    now = time()
    speed = len/(now-then) * weight + speed * (1-weight)
    update progress display
    then=now
```

As always, network speed is an approximation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also recommend that you pass a long instead of an int.  (They aren't always the same size, and curl_easy_setopt expects a long.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAX_SEND_SPEED_LARGE, 100L)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [curl_easy_setopt](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html) documentation you need to pass a **curl_off_t** as the parameter for CURLOPT_MAX_SEND_SPEED_LARGE, which is a **long long**. (This may be new since the other answers were given.)

> CURLOPT_MAX_SEND_SPEED_LARGE
>
> Pass a curl_off_t as parameter. If an upload exceeds this speed
>   (counted in bytes per second) on cumulative average during the
>   transfer, the transfer will pause to keep the average rate less than
>   or equal to the parameter value. Defaults to unlimited speed.
>
> This option doesn't affect transfer speeds done with FILE:// URLs.
>   (Added in  7.15.5)

Example:

```
curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_MAX_SEND_SPEED_LARGE, 1024LL );
```